# Need to validate dd/mm/yy hh:mmtt in Javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, datetime, date-formatting

I am trying this to validate the date.However I am not too sure about what is wrong with this.

Note- I my application there is no space between mm(minuted) and AM/PM.

```
var date = '21/01/13 6:40AM';

var myRegex = /0?[0-31]\d\/0?[0-12]\d\/\d{2} [0-11]\d:[0-59]\d[AP][M]/; 


if (myRegex.test(date)){
// Ok to proceed

}
```

I tried the following by breaking the date and time separately i.e the following combination

```
var date = '21/01/13'

var myRegex = /0?[0-31]\d\/0?[0-12]\d\/d{2}/;
```

However for the time part i.e 6:40AM.I am not able to validate it with

```
var myRegex = /[0-11]\d:[0-59]\d[AP][M]/;
```

Could you please help me out.

Comment: With two digit years you need to decide where the break is between 1900 and 2000.

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

`var regex = /^([0-11]\d):([0-59]\d)\s?(?:AM|PM)?$/i;`

`Will work for : "06:40am"`

Comment: It will also allow '18:95AM'. Try: `/^(0?[0-9]|1[0-2]):([0-5][0-9])(AM|PM)$/i`

Answer (score 1):

Try This One. Leap year supported.   example: http://jsfiddle.net/Vk268/

```
 ^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\/(0[13578]|1[02])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\/(0[13456789]|1[012])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/02\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29\/02\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check actual validity not just syntax. check this post which uses `datejs`

[Jquery DateJs, is there validation for full date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408202/jquery-datejs-is-there-validation-for-full-date)

Answer (score 0):

One way to validate date and time strings is to create a date object and see if the parts match, e.g.

```
function validateDateString(s) {
    var b = s.split(/[\/ :]/g);
    var ap = s.substring(-2).toLowerCase();
    var h = parseInt(b[3], 10) + (ap == 'am'? 0 : 12);
    var min = parseInt(b[4],0);
    var y = +b[2] + (b[2] < 50? 2000 : 1900);
    var d = new Date(y, --b[1], b[0], h, min, 0, 0);
    var apValid = /am|pm/.test(ap);

    // Only need to test two parts of date and hours
    return d.getMonth() == b[1] && d.getDate() == b[0] && d.getHours() == h && apValid;
}

console.log(validateDateString('21/01/13 6:40AM')); // true
```

You could use a regular expression too, and if ES5 compliant browsers are all you need to support you could reformat the string as an ISO 8601 compliant string a pass it to Date.parse. But that won't work in many browsers in use.

Comment: `validateDateString('21/01/13 11:40AM')` returns `true` for me.